# Store dictionary in UserDefaults using @Published

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have this:

```
@Published var mealsAndTime: [String: Date] = UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "mealsAndTime") {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.mealsAndTime, forKey: "mealsAndTime")
    }
}
```

and it's telling me:

> Cannot convert value of type '[String : Any]' to expected argument type '[String : Date]'

What's wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casting... UserDefaults does not know about internal values, so type is Any. You have to cast explicitly, as you know your types, but safely, just in case.

So solution is

```
@Published var mealsAndTime: [String: Date] =
    UserDefaults.standard.dictionary(forKey: "mealsAndTime") as? [String: Date] ?? [:] {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.mealsAndTime, forKey: "mealsAndTime")
    }
}
```